# Is there an API to create a Dogecoin Wallet?

Tags: dogecoin

Identical to this, but for dogecoin? https://blockchain.info/api/create_wallet

Comment: not sure why still use dogecoin as cryptocurrency as it deprecated unless you're using it for experimental purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The [block.io](https://block.io) service offers DOGE coin wallets and [an API](https://block.io/docs/basic).